# Java: Print Text With Strikethrough

Tags: java, text

I'm printing to a file. Is there a way to print the text with strikethrough through it? I have done some googling, but did not find any applicable answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to save the file in a PDF, HTML or create some kind of word processor document. Simple text (or more correctly plaintext) does not have formatting ... in any language ...

I'd recommend HTML. It is simple to create (PDF is a pain), gives you the option of other formatting (people always end up asking for a heading), allows you to format as tables (managers love tables), and will open anywhere (could even be served on a web-server, eliminating printing and tree-killing altogether).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. So if I print a file that's interpretable as, e.g. HTML, and add strikethrough tags, that's how to do it?

Comment: That would be easier to read and probably simpler to implement than @TheodorStraube 's solution. I find working with Unicode to be a pain, since you have to map each character to it's strike-through equivalent. Also, doing html gives you the option of other formatting, if you need it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force it, you can use the unicode index of those letters, like this:

```
"\u03C0" //π
```

http://unicode-table.com/de/0268/
This, as an example is the ɨ

Comment: Just like this: System.out.println("\u0268");

Comment: That's tempting, but will probably be a bigger workload than I want.